# Android change a button's text color for 2 seconds

Tags: android

I would like to change a button's text's color to green for 2 seconds, and then turn it back to original. How can I do this?
My method is:

```
private void changeColors() {
    Button option1Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option1Button);
    Button option2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option2Button);
    Button option3Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option3Button);
    Button option4Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option4Button);

    Button[] buttons = {option1Button, option2Button, option3Button, option4Button};

    buttons[correctAnswerButtonID].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
//later changing it back to original

}
```

This doesn't work, the text changes to green AFTER the sleep method. I want it to change to green, and then start the sleep process.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: what is your use case? why you want to change text color for 2 seconds?

Comment: That's a quiz game. It generates an image (as the question) and four answers for it. I want the following:
If the user clicks the correct answer button, it is changing to green for 2 seconds - showing them it was the correct answer.
If no, the clicked button turns to red, and the correct answer button turns to green. I need 2 seconds before the game generates another turn, so the player can see his answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use animation

```
buttons[correctAnswerButtonID].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
buttons[correctAnswerButtonID].animate().setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // set color back to normal
                buttons[correctAnswerButtonID].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: That's not the solution I would like to have. The program executes the methods after this, and then changes the color to green when the 2 seconds have passed.

Comment: Can you be more specific? my method change the color to green, wait 2 sec and change it back to black, like you asked in your question.